# Angularjs app not working after adding new controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Initially my controller.js looked like this

```
    function MyCtrl1() {}
MyCtrl1.$inject = [];


function MyCtrl2() {
}
MyCtrl2.$inject = [];
```

And the html code like this

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v <span app-version></span></div>
  <div>Author is : <span app-author></span></div>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the service.js code

```
    angular.module('myApp.services', []).
  value('version', '0.1')
  .value('author','Jay');
```

And the directive.js code

```
    angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
  directive('appVersion', ['version', function(version) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      elm.text(version);
    };
  }])
  .directive('appAuthor', ['author', function(author) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs){
        elm.text(author);
    };
  }]);
```

The above code worked completely worked fine and displayed `version` and `author` configured in service.js

The moment i modify my controller.js to include a new controller as below it stops working and nor the version nor the author is displayed.
The modified controller code is as below

```
    function MyCtrl1() {}
MyCtrl1.$inject = [];


function MyCtrl2() {
}
MyCtrl2.$inject = [];

angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.panes = [
    { title:"Dynamic Title 1", content:"Dynamic content 1" },
    { title:"Dynamic Title 2", content:"Dynamic content 2" }
  ];
};
TabsDemoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Any pointers why this thing is not working.

Comment: What type of error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your problem is the redeclaration of myApp here:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

I was able to reproduce your problem when I had

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services', 'myApp.directives']);
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Switching it to

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

made everything work again.

Comment: indeed dat was the issue.Thnks :)

Comment: and some further detail 
THE FIRST CONTROLLER in the controllers.js file must have //____sp____
      angular.module('myApp.controller',[])
following controllers must be defined //______sp_____
      angular.module('myApp.controller')